# How to make the bars in barplot don't start from 0 (matplotlib)

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
df = df.T
media = df.mean()
error = df.std()
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], media, yerr=error)
plt.show()
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ovoX.png)

What I want is that the bars start in the bottom of the axis instead of 0. Like this one [I used paint to show it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjY1d.png)

I need to plot the error bar also, it's part of an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the matplotlib documentation for [matplotlib.pyplot.bar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), it supports a `bottom` parameter that can be used to set the vertical baseline. You will also need to adjust the height parameter by the same amount.

```
offset = df.min().min()
plt.bar([1,2,3,4], media - offset, yerr=error, bottom=offset)
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot that doesn't start at 0]

However, you should only need to do this in very rare situations, such as where the dataframe represents values on a log scale.

As [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney) commented, barplots that don't start at y=0 would usually be considered a misrepresentation of the data (it will mislead readers), and in this case you may want to consider a boxplot instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3500), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3500), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3500), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3500)])
plt.boxplot(df)
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Thank you!!! I am aware that bars shouldn't be used in this scenario, but the assignment requieres it. I am very satisfayed with your answer, it was very usefull.